# Can I use \singlespacing to define captions to have a single-line spacing?

Tags: captions, koma-script

I'd like to try and format my captions with single-line spacing. The rest of the document is set with `\onehalfspacing`.

A brief search lead me to [this post on komascript.de](http://www.komascript.de/node/631), in which Markus wrote:

> Du kannst der Schrift für caption wahlweise ein `\linespread{1}\selectfont` oder die entsprechende setspace-Anweisung hinzufügen. \singlespacing sollte hingegen an der Stelle nicht verwendet werden, weil das ggf. zusätzlichen vertikalen Abstand einfügt.

=>

> You can use both `\linespread{1}\selectfont` or the respective `setspce`-command. However in this case, `\singlespacing` should be avoided since it might add additional vertical space.

Although roughly 7 years ago, I rather ask than not: should I still use rather `\linespread{1}\selectfont` instead of `\singlespacing`?

Comment: I just recently ran into that problem (e.g. extra vertical space when using `\singlespacing`) with the following code `\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\singlespacing}` using the `etoolbox` package to make all tables single spaced. `\linespread{1}` fixed that. Unfortunately, I don't know why `setspace` behaves that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you shouldn't worry about single or double spacing in captions, except if you use `\captionof` (see later). This example shows that captions and footnotese are set in single spacing by default:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

A footnote\footnote{\lipsum*[2]} \lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}
\centering
\LARGE A FIGURE
\caption{\protect\lipsum*[2]}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\centering
\LARGE A TABLE
\caption{\protect\lipsum*[2]}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Regarding `\captionof`, its main usage should be for adding a caption in a “mixed float” with both a figure and a table that we don't want to separate from each other.

If you use `\captionof` (always in an environment, never at the outer level) not in `figure` or `table` you have to set single spacing yourself. Use `\linespread{1}\selectfont` for this, because `\singlespacing` is defined by

```
% setspace.sty, line 345:
\newcommand{\singlespacing}{%
  \setstretch {\setspace@singlespace}%  normally 1
  \vskip \baselineskip  % Correction for coming into singlespace
}
```

and you see clearly that a vertical space is added.

Alternatively you can use `\setstretch{1}\selectfont`

```
% setspace.sty, line 317:
\newcommand{\setstretch}[1]{%
  \def\baselinestretch{#1}%
  \@currsize
}
```

because it does other adjustments to spacing parameters.

Comment: Regardless of my confusion about `\captionof`, this answer is quite clear whether one should `\singlespacing`. :)

Comment: @henry I'll clarify.